# Maximize $\ S=Max{(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} |f(i+1)-f(i)|)}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, discrete-optimization

Let $\ f: \{1,2,...n\} → \{1,2,...n\} \quad bijection$

What I want to know is

$\ S=Max{(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} |f(i+1)-f(i)|)}$

Furthermore, Is there a way to know 'when' does S would be maximized?

I could find the solution as [n^2/2]-1 and method for every n 
but  hard to prove that it is maximum.

Comment: Not if I haven't a clue about what $f$ is.

Comment: @KennyLau Presumably it is the bijection which maximises $S$.

Comment: @KennyLau I'll fix it more specifically.

Comment: Here's [a program in Pyth](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.MsaVtZPZ.p&input=4&debug=0) to use brute force to tackle your question.

Comment: @KennyLau Wow! that's really amazing!

Comment: @KennyLau MsaVtZPZ.p << what does it mean?? How could it solve my problem with that short words?

Comment: The rightmost `.p` is "all permutations of". The leftmost `M` is "find elements in the list such that the following is maximum:". `s` is sum of, `a` is absolute difference, `V` is applied in parallel, `tZ` is all but first element of `Z`, `PZ` is all but last element of `Z`.

Comment: Translated to pseudocode: `filter_for_maximum (function Z:(sum(absolute_difference_in_parallel(all_but_first(Z),all_but_last(Z))))) in all_permutations_of(input)`

Comment: I hope you understand this.

Comment: Here's [a program in Jelly](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZIhSUFT4oKs4bmAClLDh-KCrA&input=&args=Nw&debug=on) that find the maximum of the sum from `n=1` to specified.

Comment: @KennyLau I have never learned about Python but I could understand a little bit. For your help, I could realize that Python is really powerful.

Comment: That is not Python, that is Pyth. Pyth is a language based on Python mainly used for code-golfing.

Comment: (In case you are wondering, I am from [PPCG](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the triangle inequality, we have, with $\mu=\frac{n+1}2$,

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left|\,f(i+1)-f(i)\right|
&\le
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\left|\,f(i+1)-\mu\right|+\left|\,f(i)-\mu\right|\right)
\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^n\left|k-\mu\right|-|\,f(1)-\mu|-|\,f(n)-\mu|
\\
&=\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}2\right\rfloor-|\,f(1)-\mu|-|\,f(n)-\mu|
\\
&\le\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}2\right\rfloor-1\;.
\end{align}

Equality holds if all neighbouring pairs are on opposite sides of $\mu$ and $f(1)$ and $f(n)$ are $\lfloor\mu\rfloor$ and $\lceil\mu\rceil$. Since we have the same number of elements on either side of $\mu$, this is possible; see [OEIS entry A047838](https://oeis.org/A047838) for one concrete arrangement.

Comment: Wow! Very simple and nice!

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to get upper bound.

$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} |f(i+1)-f(i)|= ±1±1±2±2 ...±n±n$
$≤-1-1-2-2...+(n-1)+(n-1)+n+n) =⌊{n^2}/{2}⌋−1$

$'±'$ means choosing $'+'$or $'-' $

so we can get upper bound $⌊{n^2}/{2}⌋−1$